# Errors when viewing pages with children in admin UI after DB migration

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, wagtail

After migrating our project from MySQL to PostgreSQL, parts of the admin UI has broken. When navigation to pages with children, an error is thrown which seems to originate from Wagtail core. Here's the log:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://beta.detfri.dk/admin/pages/3/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['home',
 'search',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail.core',
 'modelcluster',
 'taggit',
 'colorfield',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.legacy.sitemiddleware.SiteMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_page_title_explore.html, error at line 6
   operator does not exist: character = uuid
LINE 1: ...."id") WHERE "wagtailcore_page"."translation_key" = '1c0af87...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

   1 : {% load i18n wagtailadmin_tags %}
   2 : 
   3 : {# The title field for a page in the page listing, when in 'explore' mode #}
   4 : 
   5 : &lt;div class="title-wrapper"&gt;
   6 :      {% if page.is_site_root %} 
   7 :         {% if perms.wagtailcore.add_site or perms.wagtailcore.change_site or perms.wagtailcore.delete_site %}
   8 :             &lt;a href="{% url 'wagtailsites:index' %}" class="icon icon-site" title="{% trans 'Sites menu' %}"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
   9 :         {% endif %}
   10 :     {% endif %}
   11 : 
   12 :     {% if page_perms.can_edit %}
   13 :         &lt;a href="{% url 'wagtailadmin_pages:edit' page.id %}" title="{% trans 'Edit this page' %}"&gt;{{ page.get_admin_display_title }}&lt;/a&gt;
   14 :     {% else %}
   15 :         {{ page.get_admin_display_title }}
   16 :     {% endif %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (operator does not exist: character = uuid
LINE 1: ...."id") WHERE "wagtailcore_page"."translation_key" = '1c0af87...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/auth.py", line 187, in overridden_render
    return render()
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 302, in render
    match = condition.eval(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 876, in eval
    return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 670, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 795, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 857, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py", line 989, in is_site_root
    return Site.objects.filter(root_page__translation_key=self.translation_key).exists()
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 777, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 538, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1121, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1151, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/var/www/detfri.dk/detfri/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/pages/3/
Exception Value: operator does not exist: character = uuid
LINE 1: ...."id") WHERE "wagtailcore_page"."translation_key" = '1c0af87...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

And, if it should be needed, some info on the system:

```
    Python version: 3.8.10
    Django version: 3.0.6
    Wagtail version: 2.12.3
    PostgreSQL version: 12.9
    Operating system: Ubuntu Server 21.04
```

I'm at a loss here - any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think wagtailcore_page model and its database schema are not similar. Can you add them?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I think when I moved the data from sqlite3 to postgresql the wagtailcore_page column translation_key got changed to column type 'integer' from 'uuid'. The problem is solved by changing translation_key to 'uuid' by using the following Postgres command:

```
ALTER TABLE "wagtailcore_page" ALTER COLUMN "translation_key" SET DATA TYPE UUID USING "translation_key"::UUID;
```